Equivalence Relation On Naturals From Subgroups of $\mathbf{Q}_{>0}$
Denote the natural numbers by $\mathbf{N} = \{1, 2, 3, \cdots \}$.
Let $G \subseteq \mathbf{Q}_{>0}$ (multiplicative group of positive rationals). Define an equivalence relation $R$ (depending on the choice of subgroup $G$) for $a, b \in \mathbf{N}$ where $aRb$ if and only if $\frac{a}{b} \in G$.
Indeed, we get that $R$ is an equivalence relation since
$G \ni 1 = \frac{a}{a}$, and so $aRa$ (reflexivity)
$aRb \implies \frac{a}{b} \in G$ meaning $(\frac{a}{b})^{-1} = \frac{b}{a} \in G$ and so $bRa$ (symmetry)
If we assume $aRb$ and $bRc$ then $\frac{a}{b} \cdot \frac{b}{c} = \frac{a}{c} \in G$ and so $aRc$ (transitivity).
For example, if $G = \mathbf{Q}_{>0}$ we get one class under $R$ since all naturals $\{1, 2, 3, \cdots\}$ are related via $R$.
For another example, if $G$ is the subgroup generated by the set $\{ \frac{p}{q} : p, q \in \mathbf{P} \}$, then the naturals get split into classes depending on the total number of prime factors:
$\{1\}$
$\{p: p \in \mathbf{P}\}$
$\{pq: p, q \in \mathbf{P} \}$
$\{pqr: p, q, r \in \mathbf{P} \}$
$\cdots$
I'm trying to find whether this relation has previously been studied, especially in the context of classifying subgroups of the multiplicative group of rationals.

One thing to note: ${\frac pq: p,q\in P}$ is not a subgroup because the product of elements of $G$ isn't necessarily a member of $G$; e.g. $\frac23\cdot\frac25=\frac4{15}$. If you mean the subgroup generated by $\frac pq$ over all prime $p,q$ then that's actually somewhat more complicated.

@StevenStadnicki Thanks for the correction. That is what I meant.

Also, your characterization of the equivalence classes under this subgroup is incorrect; there are exactly two equivalence classes and it's rather a fun exercise to figure out what they are.

@StevenStadnicki Yes, sorry I can see that now also. I've removed that example for now but will think about it some more. Thanks!

@StevenStadnicki "there are exactly two equivalence classes". I don't think this can be true since one of the classes is clearly $\mathbf{P}$ but then $8$ and $4$ should belong to different classes since otherwise $\frac{8}{4} = 2 \in G$ but we can see that the only integer in this subgroup is 1. Or am I missing something?

@StevenStadnicki I believe this subgroup splits $\mathbf{N}$ depending on the total number of prime factors

Are you familiar with quotient groups?

Antosha: you're right, I misfigured somewhere and thought it was 'just' a parity thing but the number of prime factors top and bottom of each element in that subgroup are the same, so that's the equivalence it induces on N.

Your equivalence relation is naturally related to the structure of the quotient group $\mathbb{Q}_{>0}/G$. Indeed, we see directly from the definition that each equivalence class is obtained by intersecting $\mathbb{N}$ with a coset of $G$.
So, structurally speaking, what do we obtain? As a starting point, notice that the monoid $(\mathbb{N}_{>0},\cdot)$ is the free commutative semigroup on countably many generators (the primes). Similarly, $\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$ is the free abelian group on the same generating set. As such, the quotient group $\mathbb{Q}_{>0}/G$ can be any countable abelian group (with a distinguished sequence of generators given by the images of the primes), inside of which $\mathbb{N}/\sim$ sits as the semigroup generated by this same sequence.
There are a lot of possible results of this construction, in fact every cancellative commutative semigroup arises in this way. As a little exercise, I can recommend checking that this translation process works both ways. That is, if you start with any cancellative commutative semigroup generated by a distinguished sequence of elements, you can recover from that a unique subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$. (For instance, the semigroup $(\mathbb{N}_0,+)$ with the constant sequence $(1,1,1,...)$ should lead you right back to your second example in the question.)

Edit: As per the comment, I will expand on that last example a bit. First, let's see how the result $(\mathbb{N}_0,+)$ with sequence $(1,1,1,...)$ comes about in the first place starting from $G=\langle \frac{p}{q}: p,q \in \mathbb{P} \rangle$. To see the equivalence relation induced on $\mathbb{N}$, we first need to compute the quotient $\mathbb{Q}_{>0}/G$ and then look at the semigroup generated by the images of the primes. Now, it is not hard to see that $G$ is exactly the kernel of the homomorphism
$$\nu: \mathbb{Q}_{>0}\to \mathbb{Z}, r\mapsto \sum_{p\in \mathbb{P}}\nu_p(r),$$
where $\nu_p$ denotes the $p$-valuation. In fact, $\nu$ is clearly onto, so that the quotient is given by $\mathbb{Q}_{>0}/G\simeq \mathbb{Z}$ via $\nu$. Under this identification, every prime is sent to the same element $1\in \mathbb{Z}$, so that the distinguished sequence is really the constant sequence $(1,1,1,...)$. Moreover, it is now clear that the semigroup generated by this sequence is really $\mathbb{N}_0$. (This matches up with your computation given in the question, in which you noticed that the equivalence classes simply count the number of prime factors.)
Now, to see how to do this process in reverse, let's start with a different result and see which subgroup $G$ corresponds to it. Suppose we are handed the cancellative commutative semigroup $V=\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ (yes, this is actually an abelian group) with the sequence of generators given by $(e_1,e_2,e_3,...)$, where $e_n$ denotes the $n$-th unit vector. To recover the subgroup $G$ from that, we will have to look at the homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Q}_{>0}\to V$ that sends the $n$-th prime to $e_n$ and determine its kernel. For this example, this is once again straightforward - the kernel $G$ is exactly the subgroup of squares.

Thanks for your answer! Could you just clarify a few things? What exactly do you mean by "each equivalence class is obtained by intersecting N with a coset of G". Do I understand correctly that we're looking for naturals inside the cosets of G, which would consist of rationals?
Also, could you elaborate on how exactly the sequence $(1, 1, 1, \cdots )$ with the N_0 semigroup correspond to my example?

@Antosha I edited the answer to give some more details on the example just now. And for the first question, yes, that is exacatly what I meant.
